# how to query elasticsearch based on documentid

Tags: elasticsearch

Failed to deserialize exception response from stream error while query on Id based query in elastic search. but when I execute the following query.

```
client.prepareSearch(index)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
     .addField("aa.ct")
     .addField("aa.bb")
     .addField("a.aa") .
```

It works but I need to search based on Id of document.

```
  SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("dbIndex")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_id","532adfdxfe8343000458ffd3"))
    .setExplain(true)
    .setQuery().setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `prepareGet` and set the ID.

```
GetResponse response = esClient.prepareGet()
    .setIndex("dbIndex")
    .setType("yourType")// set the index type as well
    .setId("532adfdxfe8343000458ffd3")
    .setFields(new String[]{"aa.ct", "aa.bb", "a.aa"})
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get method to search for an _id. (Its not actual searching but a kind of that)
It returns the record if it really exist, else in the json response, it will say, exists: false.